# Calling CreateService when explicitly specifying the local domain in lpServiceStartName errors out

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm creating a service on a machine in C# via a win32 API call to `CreateService`. The MSDN page for that function says about the `lpServiceStartName` param:

> The name of the account under which the service should run. If the
>   service type is SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS, use an account name in the
>   form DomainName\UserName. The service process will be logged on as
>   this user. If the account belongs to the built-in domain, you can
>   specify .\UserName.

On the remote machine, the user `myuser` belongs to the default local domain `WORKGROUP`. If I pass `".\myuser"`, everything works fine. If I pass `"WORKGROUP\myuser"`, I get `ERROR_INVALID_SERVICE_ACCOUNT`.

I'm curious about this behavior, as the above docs seem to say I *can* specify `.\myuser`, not that I *must*. Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: Did you make any progress regarding the issue? I might have a similar issue on my plate...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'm not an expert in windows account management, and I may get a few downvotes here, but here is what I noticed when I was testing windows services log on identities.
As documentation states, you can specify ".\UserName" if the account belongs to the built-in domain. Built-in domain includes groups and users created when OS is installed ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/wms721755(v=vs.85).aspx)).
So instead of ".\UserName", you can specify "BUILTIN\UserName" since BUILTIN is the name of the built-in domain.

In practice, it worked for "BUILTIN\Administrators" and "BUILTIN\Guests", but it didn't work for user "BUILTIN\Guest".
If you try to create a new local group and local user and set it as a log on identity, you will still see it in a form ".\UserName". This may be inaccuracy in documentation, but in any case, for local user accounts that are not built-in accounts you can replace the dot with machine name: "MACHINE\UserName".